# CodeIgniter index.php URL rewriting OVH

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2, virtualhost

I readed a lot of topics about this subject but no one worked.

First i share my configs:

Vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName lacangolf.raphaelaupee.fr
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/raphael/lacangolf/public_html"
        <Directory /var/www/raphael/lacangolf/public_html>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        #ErrorLog
        #LogLevel warn
        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Conf file:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I tryed to replace Auto by theses 4 solutions but didn’t work. ‘PATH_INFO’  ‘QUERY_STRING’  ‘REQUEST_URI’   ‘ORIG_PATH_INFO’

My application skelet is:

CodeIgniter index.php rewriting problem

```
|-application
|-system
|-public_html
  |-assets
  |-index.php
  |-.htaccess
```

Thanks for helping i m still searching a solution with my friend google. (sorry about my bad english)

Comment: Update: Tryed another config i shared there http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237309/