# Codeigniter works fine without index.php on the url in localhost but not in server

Tags: php, codeigniter

its bean 2 days that im trying to  solve that problem.
I need to remove the index.php  from the URL,
my conf is good

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywebsite/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

(I changed the uri_protocol and tryied all the suggested values)

The .htaccess file is good to,

I tried to many suggestions on the .htaccess and here is the last one :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

here is the disposition of the files :

```
- bin
- etc
- mail
- public_ftp
- public_html
 -- application
 -- assets
 -- system
 -- .htaccess
 -- index.php
```

As you see, my application is on the `public_html` file, my server is using the cpanel accelerator 2 for the configuration, and i cant access the httpd.conf to see if the `AllowOverride` is setted to `ALL`.

How could i fix that problem ?

Comment: in config.php, I use: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Comment: (fyi) my .htaccess file has file permissions: 705

Comment: Also see these 2 links: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html and http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/155801/

Comment: i dont think its about my .htaccess file, i changed it to many times with all the ways possible but it still dont work

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. Can you show your virtualhost file please
edit:added my topic subject [CodeIgniter index.php URL rewriting OVH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236711/codeigniter-index-php-url-rewriting)

2nd edit:
Try to remove the first / on your .htaccess like this RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: where can i find my virtualhost file ?

i remove the / but still it doesnt work

Comment: how can i access to the files with ssh ?