# Code Igniter Clean URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm dealing with this URL. I'm workin on a proyect where I've have this URL:

```
http://localhost/franca/menkenPh/index.php/controller/argument/argument
```

But I need that i turns into something like:

```
http://localhost/franca/menkenPh/0/cirug
```

How can I achive that?

I try to do this on the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /franca/menkenph/
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I go to URL I want it give me page not found error and when i do:

```
    http://localhost/franca/menkenPh
```

It tells me that the arguments are missed.

Any clue?

Comment: we are a lot getting this problem if u fix it please share it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236711/codeigniter-index-php-url-rewriting

Comment: Make sure `mod_rewrite` [is enabled](http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/8-mod-rewrite-on-localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your application/config/config.php remove index.php from the base url.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/franca/menkenPh';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then go to your routes the add

```
$route['/(:any)/(:num)'] = "maincontroller/index/$1/$2";
```

So the method should be index() but no arguments at all just use uri class and locate those two uri segments

```
$arg1 = $this->uri->segment(3,0);
$arg2 = $this->uri->segment(4,0);
```

Your rewrite base should be

```
RewriteBase /franca/menkenph/
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't say it but I have this route: $route['site/(:any)'] = 'site/index/$1';

Comment: Sorry, but cirug is an argument, the URL that I need is controller/argument/argument :)

Comment: Sorry, but like what?

Comment: No, i think that mod rewrite isn't workin. If I do: http://localhost/franca/menkenPh/ it goes to the mainController but if i add something to that URL I don't know where it is going, looking another controller?

Comment: I think you have to define your mainController as your default controller as well

Comment: So the name of your controller is Site?

Comment: yeap, it is the only one.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /franca/menkenPh/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Try this htaccess